# How to extract information from a html select array option?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to create a html select array option like the following

```
<select name="tablename">
    <option value="['one','two','three']">Option one</option> 
</select>
```

in javascript

```
 var myArray = new Array(); 

myArray[0] ="one";
myArray[1] ="two";
myArray[2] = "three";

 option.value=myArray;
```

but when i try to get value from it using

```
var myArray2 = new Array();
myArray2 = $('select[name="tablename"]').val();
val=myArray2[0];
```

it did not return anything...anything went wrong

Answer (score 2):

Option value can store string only. You can store array in some stringified form, and parse it in JS. Eg:

```
<select name="tablename">
    <option value="['one','two','three']">Option one</option> 
</select> 

// JS
var myArray2;
myArray2 = $('select[name="tablename"]').val();
myArray2 = eval(myArray2);
alert(myArray2[0]);
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/kZape/

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what exactly you want to do, but if you want to store array `["one","two","three"]` into single `OPTION` and then read this array from javascript, you can do next:

HTML:

```
<select name="tablename">
    <!-- IMPORTANT COMMENT: use single quotes for value='' and double quoutes for values in array -->
    <option value='["one","two","three"]'>Option one</option>
</select>
```

jQuery:

```
// reading array from OPTION
var myArray2 = jQuery.parseJSON($('select[name="tablename"]').val());
// myArray2 now is an javascript Array
console.info(myArray2);
```

**UPDATE**:

You can use native javascript `JSON` object methods to convert Array into string and then store into html OPTION or SELECT value; or to convert value of OPTION or SELECT into Array (*if you not need to support IE version less than 8*):

```
// store Array into OPTION value
myOption.value = JSON.stringify(["one","two","three"]);

// read Array from SELECT value from your example
var newArray = JSON.parse($('select[name="tablename"]').val());
```

Read more aboute `JSON.parse()` and `JSON.stringify` in MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc836458%28v=VS.94%29.aspx and in MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON

Answer (score 0):

First, edit your markup.

```
<option value="[one,two,three]">Option one</option>
```

Get the value of option tag.

```
v = $('option').val();
```

'v' would be "[one,two,three]" in string object.

```
v = v.slice(1, -1);
```

then, it is "one, two, three"
now split it,

```
yourArray = v.split(',');
```

finally you get yourArray ["one", "two", "three"]
 :)